# How to correctly form a sentence that has an “als auch” construct

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

I have some doubts how to properly write a sentence in German. Since I have *als auch* in it I am a bit confused. The sentence is coming from a scientific text, so don’t be shocked by the funny terms.

> Um dieses Ziel zu erreichen, habe ich Methoden sowohl für die
>   Verbesserung der mathematischen Modelle, als auch die numerische
>   Effizienz der Löser eingebracht und umgesetzt.

I am basically not sure whether the *Satzbau* is correct. A friend of mine told me that this sentence sounds odd in German. This is why I would like to ask for the opinion of a native speaker about it.

Comment: Welcome, but note that [Stack Exchange is not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/is-stack-overflow-a-forum) (which is also why I removed the greeting from your post). See also the [help] for more information about how this site works and what is on-topic here. General proofreading questions (“What’s wrong with this text?”) are not considered good questions for German.SE.

Comment: Perhaps you can see the (logical, not so much grammatical) problem with this sentence yourself if you break it up into its two parts: _Ich habe Methoden für die Verbesserung der mathematischen Modelle eingebracht und umgesetzt. Ich habe Methoden die numerische Effizienz der Löser eingebracht und umgesetzt._

Comment: Hint: "als auch" is the second half of a pair that is almost a set phrase. So re. @chirlu's comment, *the first sentence* is missing something.

Comment: @chirlu ^^ "für" im 2. Satz fehlt?

Comment: @chirlu as Stephie wrote, I am missing a "für" in the second sentence? I am starting to float here. I would say that the following should be OK $Um dieses Ziel zu erreichen, habe ich Methoden sowohl für die Verbesserung der mathematischen Modelle UND DIE numerische Effizienz der Löser eingebracht und umgesetzt.$

Comment: Ah! Here's the missing [*sowohl*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/sowohl___als_auch)! I think you are almost able to answer your own question now...? (Well done, btw!)

Comment: @Alexander Cska: Do you want to say that you improved the efficiency?

Comment: @chirulu Yes, "I improved the mathematics models and the numeric efficiency".

Comment: @Stephie well thanks, but as far as I understand something is still missing.

Comment: I think the meaning of the sentence is: ... als auch _für_ die numerische Effizienz...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *sowohl … als auch* (i.e. *not only … but also*) construct may be used to connect two parts of a sentence similar to *und*. When using this we have to take care that the logic behind each part remains intact. For the eample in question we could use the long form:

> Um dieses Ziel zu erreichen, habe ich sowohl **Methoden für die Verbesserung** der mathematischen Modelle als auch **Methoden für die Verbesserung** der numerischen Effizienz der Löser eingebracht.

We now know that both sentence parts are the result of *introducing methods for improvement*. To avoid redundancy and to shorten the sentence we can move the identical parts to the front of the *sowohl … als auch* construct:

> Um dieses Ziel zu erreichen, habe ich **Methoden für die Verbesserung** sowohl der mathematischen Modelle als auch der numerischen Effizienz der Löser eingebracht.

---

We can of course also move only parts of the common construct outside of the *sowohl … als auch* construct:

> Um dieses Ziel zu erreichen, habe ich **Methoden für** sowohl die Verbesserung der mathematischen Modelle als auch die Verbesserung der numerischen Effizienz der Löser eingebracht.
>
> Um dieses Ziel zu erreichen, habe ich **Methoden** sowohl für die Verbesserung der mathematischen Modelle als auch für die Verbesserung der numerischen Effizienz der Löser eingebracht.

Likewise we can use the construct to use a different noun in each part e.g.

> Um dieses Ziel zu erreichen, habe ich **Methoden für** sowohl die Verbesserung der mathematischen Modelle als auch die Effizienzsteigerung der numerischen  Löser eingebracht.

Comment: now I understand clearly how to write the sentence properly. I was not sure about the als auch construct, but due to your answer I learned quite a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Considering your comment that the intended meaning is

> I improved the mathematics models and the numeric efficiency

I would say

> Um dieses Ziel zu erreichen habe ich Methoden sowohl zur Verbesserung der mathematischen Modelle als auch der numerischen Effizienz der Löser eingebracht und umgesetzt.

You have *Mehoden zur Verbesserung* eingebracht. Verbesserung wessen? *Verbesserungen sowohl der Modelle als auch der Effizienz der Löser*.

I studied Maths and Computer Science and I can tell you that, yes, sometimes the language used in scientific texts sounds a bit strange. :-)

Comment: vielen Dank für ihr Antwort.